# how do I save asciio drawings in a format which is suitable for editing later?

Tags: ascii-art

I'm using [asciio](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Asciio/lib/App/Asciio.pm) for creating graphics to use in documentation blocks of my source codes.

But the problem is, when I want to change just a little bit of my drawings, I have to draw whole thing from the beginning because when I save the file, it "renders" the drawing just like a raster image editor renders image in `png` format, so there is no going back to the "project".

It's something like I draw something in Autocad and instead of saving file in dxf format, it only saves the screenshot.

There should be a solution for this, for example I might save the memory contents to a file in order to retrieve the "project".

Is there any easier way to save the drawing something like dxf format?

Comment: Reading the manual: it's an interactive program and it doesn't appear to have a native 'save' format of the (manual!) interactions. So that seems to be a "no", then.

Comment: Why I can not see these parts of manual? :( Sorry for this...

Comment: Hm... it's at http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Asciio/lib/App/Asciio.pm but re-reading it, it seems there are *open / save* commands as well as (which I read first) "export". Not having it installed myself: what are "Open" and "Save" for, if not a 'native' format?

Comment: there is only `open` / `save` / `save as` commands available. there is no native format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of Asciio.

- Asciio saves in multiple formats, it's in the documentation.
- There is a native format, a format that let's you re-open the file and editing; it doesn't
  have a special extension, any extension that's not reserved is native format.
- Special extensions include ".txt" in that case you get a text file containing the rendering of what you see in asciio. There's also png and svg.
- You can also copy the text while in asciio and paste it in another application.

Comment: I can't install Asciio on Debian (installed via cpan but I still can't figure out how to run it). I'll confirm when I could run the app. Thanks.

Comment: try your luck with these https://pkgs.org/download/asciio. your distro  may not support gtk2 any longer and then you're out of luck. 

The latest asciio is here https://github.com/nkh/P5-App-Asciio and it uses gtk3 (it's also a completely different beast, much faster, supports unicode, Chinese, ...) but it's not packaged for CPAN yet.

try and let me know where things don't work.

Answer (score -1):

open/save/save as  ... save in the native format, just put "asciio"  as a file extension, you can use other extensions as long as it's not one reserved by the exporters (read below)

if you want a text file, IE: some bare ascii codes to put in another text file, save the file with a .txt extension. Yes it's the extension that decides how to export it (and it's clearly stated in the documentation).

for the problem you have, editing, you will have to save a file in the native format, when you want to modify the text file where you have pasted the ascii rendering, you need to delete the old one, edit the file you have saved, save it in native format (for future usage, export it as a .txt (or select and copy to the clipboard) and then insert that in your text file.

it should be pretty easy to write a vim macro that does that given you have the name of the asciio file and the height of the text you inserted (or a tag).

Comment: interesting how this answer get a minus! I wrote Asciio.